# Writing multiple logical operators more concisely

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I'm trying to write multiple logical operators in a more concise way. In my case, I want the function to only run when all four inputs are only numbers. The only way I can think of doing this is to write them all in one if statement with &&, use multiple ifs (as below), or use switch. But I was wondering if there is a more concise way.

```
    function fn() {

    const input = display.getInput();

    if (input.p !== "" && !isNaN(input.p)) {

        if (input.d !== "" && !isNaN(input.d)) {

            if (input.s !== "" && !isNaN(input.s)) {

                if (input.y !== "" && !isNaN(input.y)) {

                    if (input.y <= 100) {

                        /* run code */
                    } 
                }
            }
        } 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer exactly what you area asking, you could do it like this:

```
if (input.p !== "" && !isNaN(input.p) && input.d !== "" && !isNaN(input.d) ...
```

But in fact you should write it better. First implement a validation function:

```
function isValid(property) {
    return property !== "" && !isNaN(property);
}
```

So the if would be like:

```
if (isValid(input.p) && isValid(input.d) && ...
```

And finally, you might want to put everything into a new function:

```
function isEverythingValid(input) {
    for (let property of ["p", "d", "s", "y"]) {
        if (!isValid(input[property])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return input.y <= 100;
}
```